# how to send second result in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, bots, whatsapp

i want to make Whatsapp bot and integrated to my website. the system send the qr and users scan it through my website and after users scan and connected i want to send a message to the users it had been connected in the same page. but i got this error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```
app.get("/create", (req, res) => {
if (req.query["session"] != undefined && req.query["session"] != "") {
  venom.create(
    `${req.query['session']}`,
    (base64Qr, asciiQR, attempts, urlCode) => {
      res.send(`<img src="${base64Qr}"></img>`)
    },
    (statusSession, session) => {
      console.log("Status Session: ", statusSession);
    },
    { logQR: false, disableWelcome: true 
    }).then(() => {
      res.write("Connected!");
      res.end();
    })
} else {
  res.json({ status: "Error", messages: "Wrong Parameters" });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

res.send() can only be called once. You cannot call this function 2 or more times for a single request.

Comment: so how i can send a result to the user if the users already connected or not?

Comment: I dont know what library you are using or how it works but I know that res.write() and res.end() is causing the issue. If you must send the image and the connected message to the user I suggest you do it in a json.